# How do I assign different event handlers to elements and their parent

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

Say I have structure like:

```
<ul id="a">text
    <li id="b">text</li>
    <li id="c">text</li>
</ul>
```

How can I assign different event handlers (say, onclick listener) to a, b and c? When I assign a handler to `<ul>`, it will be triggered when any of the `<li>` is clicked.

Comment: Why dont you try based in tag id's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of setting a single handler for each element inside your list it's better to use a single event listener on the parent and, using event delegation, detect which is the id of the element the user clicked

```
$('ul').on('click', function(evt) {
   id = evt.target.id;
   switch (id) {
      "a" : ... break;
      "b" : ... break;
      "c" : ... break;
      default: ... ;
   }   

});
```

Comment: This would be the way i would do this :) +1

Comment: So, what you are basically saying is, one should apply a single eventhandler to the body element and delegate from there?

Comment: no, it's not necessary capture the event on the body. Just on the first parent is enough. and it's more performant than setting a lot of handlers

Comment: @Amberlamps, it's a balance between number of event handlers, efficiency of DOM bubbling, and clarity/robustness of code. IMO, this answer strikes a good balance between these things. A single document-level handler for all events would not strike this balance.

Comment: (+1 for this even though I posted a separate answer -- this is probably the best way to do it)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever an event is fired, it "bubbles". This means it is called on the actual element associated with it, but it is also fired once for every parent element in the chain all the way up to the top. So in your case, whenever you click on `b` or `c`, the event will *also* be fired for `a`. To avoid this, you need to stop the bubbling.

Specifically, in your event handlers for b and c, you should stop the event bubbling by doing this:

```
if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
else event.cancelBubble = true;
```

Most browsers support `stopPropagation` on the event to end the bubbling. Older versions of IE use the `cancelBubble` property. So the above should be cross-browser compatible.

I know you didn't specify jQuery, but since it's so popular, it's worth noting that if you are using jQuery, this condition is hidden behind the framework, so you can just do:

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

Answer (score 1):

Every event bubbles up the DOM tree (or at least "should", as there is IE). You may want to stop that bubbling, see [Ben Lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9767775/1048572). But there is a better way:

Just check whether the event triggering your listener was fired for the element you're watching or not. Then execute your handler, or escape.

```
document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var a = e.currentTarget; // reference to #a
    var t = e.target; // this may be #b or #c or any of their children - or not
    if (a != t)
        return;
    // else
    // do what you wanted to do
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
$('ul li#a').click(function(){
//some thing here...
});
$('ul li#b').click(function(){
//some thing here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem in one of my projects. What I did was first declared a global variable(for flag purpose and default value false). Then I triggered the onmouseover and onmouseout events on all the children and changed the flag value to true whenever the cursor is over a child ( and reverting it back to false whenever it leaves the child). So in declaring the onclick function for the parent, just put a condition to check the value of flag.